# How to access value by key in associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have made a php template. The way I use the template in the code of the index.php (homepage) is this:

```
<?php
                                require 'scripts/back_end/views/country_select.php';
                                require 'scripts/back_end/views/view.php';
                                echo View::render('select_template.php');
                            ?>
```

Now this causes this error:

```
[17-Feb-2016 05:19:34 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: options in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php on line 3
[17-Feb-2016 05:19:34 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CountrySelect, because the name is already in use in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/country_select.php on line 3
```

I think this is caused by `require`-ing country_select.php in the index.php and also in the select_template.php. I think commenting out the one in index.php is the solution to that. Here is the output `html` I get when the top `require` is commented out (refer to bottom of question to get the desired `html` output)

```
<select data-bind="options: 'options',
            optionsText: 'optionsText',
            optionsValue: 'optionsValue',
            value: value,
            optionsCaption: 'caption'"><option value="">caption</option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option><option value=""></option>
        </select>
```

Issue when commenting out the top `require`:

I'm trying to access the values of the options array in this class:

```
    <?php

class CountrySelect {

    static $template = 'select_template.php';

    public static function display() {

        if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

            // Get the full path to the template file.
            $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . static::$template;

            $viewData = array(
                "options" => '_countries',
                "optionsText" => 'name',
                "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
                "value" => 'selectedCountry',
                "caption" => 'Country'
            );

            // Return the rendered HTML
            return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

        }
        else {
            return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I'm getting these errors in the PHP console.

> [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable:
>   options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 3 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Use of
>   undefined constant options - assumed 'options' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 11 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 11 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Use of
>   undefined constant optionsText - assumed 'optionsText' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 12 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 12 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Use of
>   undefined constant optionsValue - assumed 'optionsValue' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 13 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 13 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Use of
>   undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 14 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 14 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Use of
>   undefined constant caption - assumed 'caption' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 15 [17-Feb-2016 05:15:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined
>   variable: options in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php
>   on line 15

The template that accesses the array:

```
    <?php

print_r($options);

include 'country_select.php';

?>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="select">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: '<? echo $options.options ?>',
            optionsText: '<? echo $options.optionsText ?>',
            optionsValue: '<? echo $options.optionsValue ?>',
            value: <? echo $options.value ?>,
            optionsCaption: '<? echo $options.caption ?>'">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to access the values of the associative array by key?

Here's the view.php file that has the render function:

```
    <?php

/** View.php **/

class View {

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * Render a Template.
     * -------------------------------------
     * 
     * @param $filePath - include path to the template.
     * @param null $viewData - any data to be used within the template.
     * @return string - 
     * 
     */
    public static function render( $filePath, $viewData = null ) {

        // Was any data sent through?
        ( $viewData ) ? extract( $viewData ) : null;

        print_r($viewData);

        ob_start();
        include ( $filePath );
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $template;
    }
}
?>
```

I am using [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-your-work-flow-separate-your-mark-up-from-your-logic--wp-29180)

I want my literal html template to be like this

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <div class="select">
            <span class="arr"></span>
            <select data-bind="options: _regions,
                optionsText: 'name',
                optionsValue: 'geonameId',
                value: selectedCountry,
                optionsCaption: 'Country'">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: accessing the associate array isn't the problem, it cant find the options object. Make sure it is declared in a scope at which it can see it.

Comment: @PhilWilliams Thanks. It should be able to find it because I have copied a tutorial and adapted it for my code. Is there any way to use a debugger on php code?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following? if this is available publicly,please share

Comment: `Undefined variable: options` it can't find it. Is your php included above the html at where its used?

Comment: @codeHeart Just posted the link on my question

Comment: @PhilWilliams inlcuding the file in the template causes this error: "[16-Feb-2016 10:22:33 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CountrySelect, because the name is already in use in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/country_select.php on line 3"

Comment: Shouldn't `$viewData = $options;` be `$viewData = $this->options;`

Comment: @Michael I don't think that's the issue as I tried making $viewData = the array literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The question has been heavily modified so answering completely from the start.

1. Index.php

You `CountrySelect` class is already using the `select_template.php`

So your code in index.php should be

```
<?php
    require 'scripts/back_end/views/country_select.php';
    require 'scripts/back_end/views/view.php';
    echo CountrySelect::display();


?>
```

2. Your Template :

Your `CountrySelect` class is already including the template for you, also you are passing your $viewData as

```
$viewData = array(
                "options" => '_countries',
                "optionsText" => 'name',
                "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
                "value" => 'selectedCountry',
                "caption" => 'Country'
            );
```

which is exported into the View::render() scope using `extract()` 
like this

```
( $viewData ) ? extract( $viewData ) : null;
```

which will create every key of $viewData to be a variable name, so now once extract is done, you will have 5 variables 
`$options, $optionsText, $optionsValue, $value, $caption`

so your final template should be like

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="select">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: '<?php echo $options ?>',
            optionsText: '<?php echo $optionsText ?>',
            optionsValue: '<?php echo $optionsValue ?>',
            value: <?php echo $value ?>,
            optionsCaption: '<?php echo $caption ?>'">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Doing number 1 gave this error: "16-Feb-2016 10:02:18 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/select_template.php on line 7"

Comment: What does` <?$options=>options?>` stand for? is this something related to the template engine your are using? Are you using any template engine?

Comment: There is no template engine. I use pure php. The associative array is called $options and it has a key that is also called options. My front-end uses KnockoutJS to data-bind. Yes I want to echo out the variable names into the html template. I have added a sample to the question of what the html should look like

Comment: @user3935156, what error are you getting now? after you do what is mentioned in the updated answer?

Comment: I've just fully updated the whole question in a big way. All information is new and relevant. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question again addressing the top issue and (I think) the focus should be shifted to the bottom issue. Thanks.

Comment: @user3935156 see the update, and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103673/discussion-between-user3935156-and-codeheart).